# angularjs Why dropdown not binding values in it

Tags: angularjs

Here I'm fetching data from DataBase using where condition here every textbox showing value but why dropdown not showing values

```
<select ng-options="I.CountryID as I.CountryName for I in CountryList" ng-model="CountryID">
    <option value="{{CountryName}}">{{CountryName}</option>
```

**angular.js**

```
 $scope.EditEmp = function (xxx) {
     GetAllCountryList(); var ser = Myservice.EditByid(xxx.Id);
     ser.then(function (d) {
         $scope.Name = xxx.Name;
         $scope.CountryID = xxx.CountryID;  //This is my Dropdownlist
         $('#modalpopup').modal('show')
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post here what you get in console on inspect element

Anyway, here's a simple example of what you are trying to do, this snippet was taken from angularjs site, hope it will help you.

```js
angular.module('defaultValueSelect', [])
 .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.data = {
    availableOptions: [
      {id: '1', name: 'Option A'},
      {id: '2', name: 'Option B'},
      {id: '3', name: 'Option C'}
    ],
    selectedOption: {id: '3', name: 'Option C'} //This sets the default value of the select in the ui
    };
}]);
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="defaultValueSelect" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="mySelect">Make a choice:</label>
    <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
      ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id"
      ng-model="data.selectedOption"></select>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <tt>option = {{data.selectedOption}}</tt><br/>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: by using this Linq Query im getting value                                            var x = (from n in db.Accessings
                     where n.Id == Id
                     join cts in db.Countrys on n.CountryID equals cts.CountryID
                     join sts in db.States on n.StateID equals sts.StateID
   select new  {
  n.Id, n.Email,  cts.CountryName, sts.StateName });